# How can I type dot notation for a string on Typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to build a function API that looks like this:

```js
createRoute('customers.view', { customerId: 1 });  // returns `/customers/1`
```

However, I am having troubles typing the first argument. Here's what I have so far:

```
const uris = {
  customers: {
    view: '/customers/:customerId',
  },
  users: {
    list: '/users',
  }
};

const createRoute = (route: string, routeParams: { [key: string]: string }) => {
  /**
   * This will split 'customer.view' each on a variable
   */
  const [ resource, action ] = route.split('.');

  /**
   * HERE:  I'm getting this error:
   *  
   *   Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' 
   *   can't be used to index type '{ customers: { view: string; } }'.
   *
   */
  const uri = uris[resource]?.[action]


  // ... rest of code to replace the route param...
};
```

I understand what the error means. The function signature allows me to pass any `string`, but it should be restricted to valid keys of the `uri` object.

Moreover, the second split of the string, depends on the first one (it's a nested object after all).

Is it possible to type this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your input. The approaches where either too complex or didn't actually provide type safety. Instead I went for this simpler one:

```js
const uris= {
  'customers.view': '/customers/:customerId',
  'users.list', '/users',
};

type Route = keyof typeof routePatterns;

const createRoute = (route: Route,  ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do below which let you have this::

```
createRoute(['customers', 'view'], {}); // compile
createRoute(['users', 'list'], {}); // compile
createRoute(['users', 'view'], {}); // DOESN'T compile: Type '["users", "view"]' is not assignable to type 'Route<ICustomerUri>'.
createRoute(['nota router'], {}); // DOESN'T compile: Type '"nota router"' is not assignable to type '"customers" | "users"'
```

Code:

```
interface ICustomerUri {
    customers: {
        view: string;
    };
}

interface IUsersUri {
    users: {
        list: string;
    };
}

type Route<T> = [keyof T, keyof T[keyof T]];

type Routers = Route<ICustomerUri> | Route<IUsersUri>;

interface IUris extends ICustomerUri, IUsersUri {}

const uris: IUris = {
    customers: {
        view: '/customers/:customerId',
    },
    users: {
        list: '/users',
    }
};

const createRoute = (route: Routers, routeParams: { [key: string]: string }) => {
    // your implementation
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQEkDCBXAzhAewFtYBVGEVAb2FTtST0JJlwC5rb7uA3EKAO4d8FMAHMA3FzoBfKTOChIsRCgylcsXOUo1ueLRz3d6AGxD5hEUZOmo5wBcAgBPAA5oASgWzQAPAAqAHyoALyoANoA1lAuBHCoAQA0qDFxCQHRsfGJALq5Us7uXj7QrGGo3r5QflhMxGQUIQA+laU16BpaOkGF4GWqaJ0UuKhQAB7QYAAmo3X4DTA6KZ2arDrUTkgEYPio2CMcwxYVxnSMCyzsnCb0fIIcAOQA9BfMWs9sb4vo049JdhkAP0a2uZxM5ksqBeBlY-0BjkK212EAYMCgCGgVWgFQAFDB2hxsVoUgTqgAFBAwBBEMGRNJWGy5RngMT2ACUYRC4Oez1QcQOqBARDcpigJEgmJAO0ciiQ6MxUGJuIij2+V3+0PuAkeuRSVBk7IkqF5DGIbhAYuA8oxWPaKsesNwmsekIguv1huNpu2IstUGAvJtiuVqqdLu1Hs2RpNfIAIgB5ACiAGUAHKPAJmv1ijgBYrQiIAIidRZSRe1RdyjyFozABFRCFwuBAYjACAARmLUIQewXHsTajhLo0QEFHgA6QOvBV26oO+sQBCoMllKMGmOmxOpjNZ30W3OJftFxfL1ewIs1k6L1BNlttzvd3uuDzQovqrRF1CtEugy9AA)

Answer (score 1):

This format should work for you:

```
const resource = route.split('.')[0] as keyof typeof uris;
const action = route.split('.')[1] as keyof typeof uris[typeof resource];
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBArgJwJYRgXhgbwFAxsOaEAWwFMEIAuLXPGANyVIHdqByAegKLIo8u5QS5AJIATNgBpaAX2l5C5KjTowANiijsOiilNnYZAbmynQkWMASkAhlFIAlEHHvoYACgTP71aMjAA5pIwXi6kAAo2CDbEypgwANoA1qQAnr5Q-gEAuhlZMDIAlOgAfCowHABUlbQwlTAAKgAWKDDMSGpqMBAADhqwbILCCAB0jCxsMLbATTDgMDYMUUg2AEZqpLWVHLTm0CGkEM4IwKRuofYjvf3ubCNshQkADNkLqCmpIABmMFCpPaRvvBkBATHg9rAbMAoEh5hgLqQrn0kFBbvdHgBGV42d5pIF-AFAxAoBIEwE-axHRCnbImWhVGp0eoACQAog5WdQYCI2MQYAFSFAYYFfi1UOQvAhKFs8DK8KyNmQwLAkMRkcAUWpUjAmjiFmAYGwbGBUpMyTBVqRgDZFFMAB49SkQWEG-H-M5sPxIQKTOX4Y1sWCW+AQUhiX4gGDesSkO2-d2G+JDXhxBhMVjdTLegJGAoFO5bLY7cHgfbEtzEiAJSnHGkAfhGCShMPA2VMeGsUEQBuJdLwHA4MBGw4O+yBoBjEYOfShZygTTOCJgPSiMWHI0MdL2IA2IzUIAC7istnsTjCt2TSjG6akWHwhCEvHE7AxkyKhSMQA)